# How to Use Rest Api using NSURL Session iOS 7

Tags: ios7, nsurlsession

I need to call Rest Api(POST and GET) calls when my application is in background mode. I tried read Apple documents that suggest that we can not use DATATASK in background. We can only download and upload files in BG.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score -1):

I have created a Method which uses `GET` method and sends `JSON` data to API. You can also configure your `NSURLSession` according to your requirement, I am using default session here.

```
+ (void)callGETAPIUsingSessionWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params andAPIName:(NSString *)apiName andCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *result))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"[GET] Request %@ : %@",apiName, params);

    NSString *getURL = [self addQueryStringToUrlString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",<Your Domain>,apiName] withDictionary:params];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:getURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                  {
                                      if([data length] > 0)
                                      {
                                          NSError *err = nil;
                                          NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                                          NSLog(@"[GET] Response for %@",apiName);
//                                          NSLog(@"[%@] => %@",apiName, dictResponse);
                                          completionHandler(dictResponse);
                                      }
                                      else{
                                          NSLog(@"Failed To Get Response for : %@",params);
                                          completionHandler(@{@"result":@"Failed"});
                                      }
                                  }];

    [task resume];
}
```

You can modify it to make `POST` call.

Comment: I want this in background while app is in background

Comment: This doesn't work for background tasks. Data tasks are explicitly not supported in the background.